Stability of functions vanishing to 2nd order with respect to perturbations vanishing to 3rd.
The following problem comes from the study of normal crossings degenerations, and a search for an intrinsic, differential geometric definition for normal crossings degenerations in dimension 3.
The simplest form of the question is as follows:
Take $B^3_{\epsilon}\subset \mathbb{C}^3$ a ball centered on $0$. Let $g: B^3_{\epsilon}\to \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function vanishing to third order at $0$, i.e. $\partial^{\alpha}g(0)=0$ for $|\alpha|\leq 3$. Is the function $f: B_{\epsilon}^3\to \mathbb{C}, z\mapsto z_1z_2z_3+g(z)$ right equivalent to its Taylor series at zero, i.e. does there exist a biholomorphism $\phi: B_{\epsilon}^3\to B_{\epsilon}^3$ such that $f(g(z))=z_1z_2z_3$?
A property like this is akin to the notion of stability (C.F. Singularities of Differentiable Mappings Volume 1 by Arnold et al.), but rather than seeing if precomposition by biholomorphism yields any close enough function, I only want to know if it yields close functions with Taylor series vanishing to higher order.
